# Field Name Change based on language switching

Tags: sitecore-client

I have a situation where Field name need to be changed based on language switching, calling Field name and its value into the website. Suppose, the field name is Color in English and I want to  change field name to Couleur for French Language.

[image]

Any Suggestion Please

Comment: Set a DisplayName on the template field. One for each language. But it will follow the language settings of the content editor user logged in, not the item version language if I recall correctly

Comment: Thanks Mark. If I change for one language, Field Name of other language also changing. I want to change the field name in Template that should use different name for different language

Comment: Change the DisplayName. Not the name.

Comment: I did that, Is it possible to get the DisplayName in Content? I tried it but am getting the field name instead of displayName in Content

Comment: Are you using the fieldname as a label on your frontend website? Why?

Comment: Yes, Jammy exactly we are using Fieldname as label. It was developed long back, I cannot refactor the code now

Comment: You cannot do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the item that represents your field - you will find those items in the tree underneath the template.

- To change the title shown in the editor, fill in the **Title** field
- To show a description next to the title, fill in the **Short description** field

If you need a translated "name" in your code, you need to use the display name as the name cannot be translated. Change your code to use the display name - that should do the trick.

ps: if you need help with the code, it would be best to share the current code...

Comment: Thanks Gatogordo. I tried to add Title Field but Unfortunately that didn't worked!! We have a website where we call the FIeld name. So Field Name along with Field Value need to be changed. I can change the Field value with Version Language but not the Field Name. It remaining same .

Comment: My solution will change what you see in the editor environment. What are you actually trying to do? The actual name of the field cannot be translated - and I can't see why you would want to do so...

Comment: I have to change the name of the field, the code was developed in a way that it calls field name in Website. Now we need to add a langauge for Website, Where it need to call Color(English) and Couleur (French) Field name.

Comment: Then you need to refactor your code - use the displayname instead.